# Excel dynamic spill function for rows and columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

**I need an excel function spill by columns, then rows**

I have a table in excel,

[image: BAND_TABLE]

that has columns named, band1 . . . band20, and "Test Section. want an excel function that only pulls the rows with "6F35_G2_45_44" (my example code does this).

However, I need to specify how it spills,

**Here is something I have tried so far. I am able to spill the columns (I have 6 records that match), but I cant get function to also spill downward from the coma separated values.**

```
=LET(
    xmlData, TEXTJOIN("</item><item>", TRUE, IF(BANDS_TABLE[Test Section]="6F35_G2_45_44", BANDS_TABLE[band1], "")),
    result, TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<root><item>" & xmlData & "</item></root>", "//item")),
    numRows, COUNTA(result),
    numCols, MAX(COUNTA(result)),
    finalResult, INDEX(result, SEQUENCE(numRows), SEQUENCE(1,numCols,1,1))
)
```

As you can see:

[image]

I am taking advantage of the FILTERXML() ability to spill, but what I really needs is to apply some kind of secondary spill after the firsts. The end result should be 6 columns with roughly 500 rows, that  will be used for graphing.

**Revision 1:**
Suppose I had a table like this

| Name | Version | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 2 | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10 |
| Test2 | 2 | 2.3, 5, 10, 12, 11, |
| Test3 | 4 | 14, 15, 16, |

I would need to spillover function that spills horizontally *then vertically*

| Test1 | Test2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 4 | 12 |
| 5 | 11 |
| 6 |  |
| 10 |  |

Comment: I have read your problem multiple times and I am still not sure what you want to display.  But I think you want FILTER(): `=FILTER(BANDS_TABLE[[band1]:[band20]],BANDS_TABLE[Test Section]="6F35_G2_45_44","")`

Comment: The table cells contain a sudo array, "1, 2, 3, 5, 6"" Its a string, So I need to to spill horizontally (columns) for each cell, then to spill vertically (downward) with each comma separated value.

Comment: Okay then: `=DROP(REDUCE("",FILTER(BANDS_TABLE[band1],BANDS_TABLE[Test Section]="6F35_G2_45_44",""),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(b,","))))),1)`

Comment: Wow! this is so close! I added Transpose so it give me columns instead of rows. I am getting the first as #N/A for the first column and the correctly filled values for the others
```=TRANSPOSE(DROP(REDUCE("",FILTER(BANDS_TABLE[band1],BANDS_TABLE[Test Section]="6F35_G2_45_44",""),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(b,","))))),-1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
=LET(
    X,BANDS_TABLE[Test Section],
    Y,BANDS_TABLE[NAME],
    Z,BANDS_TABLE[band1],
    mtch,"A",
    TRANSPOSE(HSTACK(FILTER(Y,X=mtch,""),DROP(REDUCE("",FILTER(Z,X=mtch,""),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(b,","))))),1))))
```

[image]

REDUCE will iterate the rows in the FILTER return and stack the results of each TEXTSPLIT.  Then we stack on the Name column, then transpose.

Comment: You are a Genius!
`=DROP(REDUCE("",FILTER(BANDS_TABLE[band1],BANDS_TABLE[Test Section]="6F35_G2_45_44",""),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(b,","))))),0)`
I just changed your earlier answer (from -1 to 0) and I am getting all 7 rows (the first one is #N/A, but the other 6 give me everything from the table)